# How to find or choose the value of k in KNN?

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour

I have a doubt regarding how to choose the value for k in KNN. I saw in many websites to take sqrt of samples. Is the sample here total number of rows or (number of rows x number of columns)? Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1):

The term "sample" is a synonym for *observational unit*. Suppose you are analyzing health data about people; your *observational unit* is a person. You might measure their height, weight and age ("features"). Whether you store that data as a row or a column is up to you.

The square root of *the number of samples* refers to the number of people about which you have measurements, and is not meaningfully related to your choice of how you stored the data.